# Populate not working for an array of ObjectIDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the implementation of my models :

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    qte : Number
});

var Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);    

var orderSchema = new Schema({
    state : {
        type: String,
        enum: ['created', 'validated', 'closed', 'starter', 'meal', 'dessert'],
        required : true
    },
    table : {
        number : {
            type : Number,
            required : true
        },
        name : {
            type : String,
            required : false
        }
    },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    _items : [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Item'}]
});
```

And this is how I do my query

```
getByIdRaw : function (orderId, callback) {
            Order.findById(orderId)
            .populate('_items')
            .exec(function(err, order) {
                debug(order);
                callback(order);
            });
        }
```

This is my response without populating

```
{
    _id: "5549e17c1cde3a4308ed70d5"
    state: "created"
    _items: [1]
        0:  "5549e1851cde3a4308ed70d6"
    -
    date: "2015-05-06T09:40:12.721Z"
    table: {
        number: 1
    }-
    __v: 1
}
```

...and my response when populating _items

```
{
    _id: "5549e17c1cde3a4308ed70d5"
    state: "created"
    __v: 1
    _items: [0]
    date: "2015-05-06T09:40:12.721Z"
    table: {
       number: 1
    }-
}
```

Why the _items array is empty ? What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT : the addItem function

```
addItem : function (orderId, item, callback) {
            Order.findById(orderId)
            .exec(function(err, order) {
                if (err) {
                    error(err);
                    return callback(err);
                }
                if (order === null) {
                    return callback("No order with this id");
                }

                var newItem = new Item({
                    name : item.name,
                    qte :item.qte
                });
                order._items.push(newItem);
                order.markModified('_items');
                order.save();
                callback();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Does the following query return anything? `Items.findById('5549e1851cde3a4308ed70d6').exec(function(err,item) {console.log(err,item);})`

Comment: Nope. It returns null. I will edit my post to show you the addItem function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the new item is never persisted to the items collection. Mongoose references only populate they don't persist a new item to the referenced collection.

```js
addItem: function(orderId, item, callback) {
  var newItem = new Item({
    name: item.name,
    qte: item.qte
  });

  newItem.save(function(err, savedItem) {
    if (err) {
      error(err);
      return callback(err);
    }

    Order.findById(orderId).exec(function(err, order) {
      if (err) {
        error(err);
        return callback(err);
      }
      if (order === null) {
        return callback("No order with this id");
      }

      order._items.push(savedItem);
      order.markModified('_items');
      order.save(callback);
    });
  });
}
```